# To push a Typescript object to an array of object in angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, javascript-objects

I am have a class as follows:

```
export class Template {
  public Id: Number;
  public FileName: string;
}
```

The following snippet is from a function where I want to first create an object (of type `Template`) and push it to the array. The code breaks at `temp.Id` with error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'Id' of undefined.

The template is initially empty. `templates` is an array that contains some file names. Array declared as: `templateObjects: Template[] = new Array();`

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.templates.length; i++)  {
  var temp: Template;
  temp.Id = i;
  temp.FileName = this.templates[i].toString();
  this.templateObjects.push(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u are not newing up Template

let temp is just declaring variable but new initialize it(allocate memory) then u will be able to assign other properties to it

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.templates.length; i++)  {
  let temp = new Template() ;
  temp.Id = i;
  temp.FileName = this.templates[i].toString();
  this.templateObjects.push(temp);
}
```

Comment: hey hanan, thanks a lot! you just solved something for me that I was struggling for hours.